# Counting number of paths between two nodes in Prolog program

Tags: algorithm, prolog, graph-theory, graph-traversal

I need some help for counting the number of combinations from which a destination node can be reached.

I found the program for finding the different paths. But in the end I need to have some query

```
%Edge List (Knowledge Base)

edge(1,2).
edge(1,4).
edge(2,4).
edge(3,6).
edge(3,7).
edge(4,3).
edge(4,5).
edge(5,6).
edge(5,7).
edge(6,5).
edge(7,5).
edge(8,6).
edge(8,7).

%Program

path(X,Y,[X,Y]):- edge(X,Y).
path(X,Y,[X|Xs]):- edge(X,W), path(W,Y,Xs).

-------------------------------------------------

%Query
path(1, 7, P).

%Results
Z = [1, 2, 4, 3, 6, 5, 7];
Z = [1, 2, 4, 3, 6, 5, 6, 5, 7];
.........................
```

But what if I want to run a query that gives me the number of these paths.

```
?-path(1, 7, count). 

should return 2
```

Comment: Well, what have you tried?

Comment: I tried counting the steps in recursion. But result is not as expected move2(X,Y,N):- N is N+1, edge(X,Y).
move2(X,Y,N):- N is N+1, edge(X,Z), move2(Z,Y,N).

Comment: `N is N+1`? That does not make any sense.

Comment: yes I know.. That's why I need help to clear my doubt

Comment: But in Prolog you can not ground a variable twice (with a different value). In that case you need a new variable. You can for instance write `N1 is N+1`.

Comment: You need to edit your question and add what code you've tried there, properly formatted. Comments are not where you put your code. But that said, from your comment, it looks like you're attempting to count node traversals, not how many total paths. The simple answer would be `findall(P, path(1,7,P), Paths), length(Paths, N)`. `N` will be your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you're answer fall into cycles and does not terminate, you could keep a list of what you've visited in order to avoid visit same nodes twice:

```
path(X,Y,L):-path(X,Y,L,[X]).

path(X,Y,[X,Y],L):- \+member(Y,L),edge(X,Y).
path(X,Y,[X|Xs],L):- edge(X,W),\+ member(W,L) ,path(W,Y,Xs,[W|L]).
```

Now if you query:

```
?- path(1, 7, P).
P = [1, 2, 4, 3, 7] ;
P = [1, 2, 4, 3, 6, 5, 7] ;
P = [1, 2, 4, 5, 7] ;
P = [1, 4, 3, 7] ;
P = [1, 4, 3, 6, 5, 7] ;
P = [1, 4, 5, 7] ;
false.
```

So the valid paths are not 2, since the above six paths are valid.

Now to count the paths you could try:

```
findall(P, path(1,7,P), Paths), length(Paths, N).
```

as suggested in comments but this is not very efficient since you need first to build a list of all paths and count the length.

If you're using Swipl you could try a fail-driven loop to calculate all possible paths and use `nb_getval/2` and `nb_setval/2` in order to count:

```
count(X,Y):-
            nb_setval(counter, 0),
            path(X,Y,_),
            nb_getval(counter, Value),
            New_value is Value+1,
            nb_setval(counter, New_value),
            fail;
            nb_getval(counter, Value),
            write(Value).
```

Example:

```
?- count(1,7).
6
true.
```

Comment: How is it less efficient to generate the paths and count them via a list than to generate them and count them using `nb_setval/2` &co.? It seems like it's the same amount of work to me, just one is ordinary Prolog and the other is not.

Comment: @DanielLyons, but with `findall` you will compute same things but you will have to to keep them in a list so this wouldn't work with large input (due to stack overflow) and also you need another O(n) in the end to compute the length...on the other hand with fail driven loop you count while computing the solutions. Computing the solutions is unavoidable in both cases.

Comment: I haven't seen stack overflows in ordinary Prolog with large inputs myself... in principle it probably happens, but I have kind of an "ick" reaction to the second half of your answer because it's pretty unidiomatic. I think of `nb_setval/2` as a tool of last resort. But yeah, for a large input, it might be necessary.

Comment: @DanielLyons ,Think about having a list (due to findall) about 10^8 paths and each path 10^6 nodes thats a lot of data and that's just a possible example...but I agree there is a tradeoff between "writing ordinary Prolog" vs avoid possible overflow...

Comment: Thank you very much. This explains my doubt very clearly! :)